# Unlock protected cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code to automatically fill up a file with data.
The file's sheet and some range is password protected
I don't know the password to unlock the sheet.
But I know the password to open the range.

Is there a way to bypass the password to unlock the range? so i can fill up the data automatically?
Thanks!

Comment: I can't find any codes that will let me just input the password to unlock the cell...
most of what I see involve unlocking the sheet first...

Comment: Not unless you want to get into some shady coding (hint: no). Use a new seperate workbook and copy the data to that or ask the owner for the password.

Comment: Alright thanks Absinthe!